# How to display posts with images in fullscreen slider

Tags: images, css

Im beginner in wordpress.I need to realize posts image  as background image slider with links on that post.I have slider like this one.[look at first slideshow.](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp)
But i cant take all images from all posts i only take image from 1st post and gave him as background please help.
This is  header.php

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="banner-image">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('banner-image'); ?></a> <!--фотка -->
    </div>
    <div class="banner-image">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('banner-image'); ?></a> <!--фотка -->
    </div>  
    <div class="banner-image">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('banner-image'); ?></a> <!--фотка -->
    </div>    
    <button class="button display-right animate-opacity" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="button display-left  animate-opacity"  onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
            </div>
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("banner-image");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.opacity = "0"  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = "1";  
}   
</script>
```

This one is functions.php

```
<?php

function learningCode(){
    wp_enqueue_style('style?v=30', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style('fonts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fonts/fonts.css' , array(), '1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/common.js' , array(), '1.0.2');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'learningCode');

function theme_setup(){
// navigation menu
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu'),
    'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu'),
));

// adding images
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_image_size('small-thumbnail', 180, 120, true);
add_image_size('banner-image');
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup');
```

[image: when im not clicked]

As u can see theres 2 buttons right and left wherever i clicked i see 1 pick in different places.default this image in up then middle and in the last 3rd click its down.

Comment: Estimating by the code that you have given, and the features that you want, I'd say that this task is a bit too difficult. It takes quite some work to achieve that or - the other option you have - you look out for a plugin that does that. Revolution Slider, Smart Slider 3 and hundrets of other "Gallery / Image" plugins are available for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code bellow with Query:

```
   <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
<?php
  $slider = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => 5,
      'post_status' => 'publish',        


  ));

  if($slider->have_posts()) :
  while($slider->have_posts()) : $slider->the_post();
?>

<div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
<a href="">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
  <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
    Trolltunga, Norway
  </div>
  </a>
</div>

  <?php 

  endwhile;
  endif;

  ?>


<button class="w3-button w3-display-left w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
<button class="w3-button w3-display-right w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>

</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
</script>
```